# why data don't display on kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui-grid

I have cod as following

```js
var loadGridEmployee = function(listEmployee) {
var grid = $("#grdemployees").data("kendoGrid");
 if (!grid) {
  grid = $("#grdemployees").kendoGrid({
         height: 600,
         columns: [
             { field: "ID", title:"ID", width: "100px" },
             { field: "Name", title:"Name", width: "150px"},
             { field: "Phone", title: "Phone", width: "150px"}              
         ],
         sortable: true,
         resizable: true,
   selectable: true,
         
         pageable: {
             pageSize: 20,
             messages: {
                 display: "{0}-{1} \/ {2}"
             }
         },
         noRecords: {
             template:"xx" + ": List is empty"
         }
     }).data("kendoGrid");
 }
 grid.dataSource.data(listEmployee);
 
 return grid;
 
}
$(document).ready(function () {
 
  var grid = loadGridEmployee(listEmployee);
 
})
```

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listEmployee = = [{"id":1,"name":"Dang Quang Hai","phone":"34563653434"}, {"id":2,"name":"Dang Gia Huy","phone":"78568534r234"}, {"id":3,"name":"Dang Hoang Linh Chi","phone":"56745745"}, {"id":4,"name":"tran binh trong","phone":"23234234r"}, {"id":5,"name":"Quang Tèo","phone":"123"}, {"id":6,"name":"hihihihih","phone":"31241"}];

</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grdemployees"></div>
<h1>Test list</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why the data did not appear on the grid.
The result I received just some titles of columns of the grid, it like the picture as follow. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bPkx.png)
Please help me
I add full what i need why STACKOVER does not agree to post this question?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry All,

I found my mistake. The name of field must be like this
ID->id, Name->name,Phone->phone. Because my table in database.